# Python: StopIteration error being raised iterating through blank csv

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, sqlite

I'm a new python user and have an issue. I apologize in advance if the solution is obvious.

I intend to be able to take a potentially large amount of csv files and jam them into a database which I can then use sql to query for reporting and other sweet stuff and I have the following code:

```
import csv

# Establishes a db connection and returns connection and cursor obj
# creates dbName.db file in given location
def openDB (dbName,location):

    import sqlite3,os

    os.chdir(location)

    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
    c = conn.cursor()

    return conn,c

# Uses connection, cursor, csv obj and writes into table
def insertFromCsv (csvObj,connection,cursor,tableName):

    c = cursor

    # Just added this condition to check for blank files
    # but I'm not sure if this is appropriate..
    rowCount = sum(1 for row in csvObj)
    if rowCount > 0:
        csvObj.next()
        i = 0
        for row in csvObj:
            tablerow = ", ".join('"' + value + '"' for value in row)
            insertSQL = "INSERT INTO '%s' VALUES (%s)" %   (tableName,tablerow)
        c.execute(insertSQL)
        i += 1

    connection.commit()
    print '%s rows committed to table %s' % (i, tableName)

# creates the .reader obj
reader = csv.reader(csvFile) 
# extract column names from csv header
tableFields = reader.next()
# formats the column names for the INSERT statement coming up
tableFields = ", ".join('"' + field + '"' for field in tableFields)

DB = openDB('foo.db','../bar')
tableName = myTable
insertFromCsv(reader,DB[0],DB[1],myTable)
```

insertFromCsv() takes as input a csv file .reader object, sqlite3 database connection and cursor objects, and an output table to create and insert into.

It has been working alright until recently when I tried to input a csv file which consisted of just a header. I got a StopIteration error after calling the .next() method. How can this be avoided/ what am I misunderstanding/overlooking?

I appreciate all the help and welcome any criticism!

Comment: What do you expect `csvObj.next()` to do? You have just exhausted the `csvObj` iterator by using `sum()` on it, so you can't read more rows at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exhausted the `csvObj` iterator on the line before:

```
rowCount = sum(1 for row in csvObj)
```

Once an iterator is exhausted, you can't call `next()` on it anymore without that raising `StopIteration`; you have reached the end of the iterator already.

If you want to test for a blank CSV file, read *one* row with the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next), which can be given a default. `next(csvObj, None)` would return `None` rather than propagate the `StopIteration` exception when the iterator is exhausted for example.

Next, use *SQL parameters* to create one generic SQL statement, then use `cursor.executemany()` to have the database pull in all the rows and insert them for you:

```
header = next(csvObj, None)
if header:
    tablerow = ", ".join(['?'] * len(row))
    insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO "%s" VALUES (%s)' % (tableName, tablerow)
    c.executemany(insertSQL, csvObj)
```

The `?` is a SQL parameter placeholder; `executemany()` will fill these from each row from `csvObj`.

It won't matter to the `cursor.executemany()` call if `csvObj` actually yieds any rows; if only the header exists and nothing more, then no actual `INSERT` statements are executed.

Note that I used `"..."` double quotes to correctly quote the table name, see [*SQLite keywords*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); single quotes are for string literal values, not table names.

Comment: Ahaaa I knew it was something I misunderstood. I actually will never expect a fully blank file, just one with only a header. does this affect anything?

Comment: @edaniley: then the `executemany()` just won't execute the SQL statements, as the `csvObj` will then be empty.

Comment: Alright! looks good except that there is no rowcount being kept for checksum purposes. is there a way to use executemany all the while counting rows?

Comment: @edaniley: you could use different techniques. You could use a loop with `for counter, row in enumerate(csvObj): c.execute(insertSQL, row)`, or you could query the number of rows in the database before and after the `executemany()` call (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "%s" % (tableName,)` as the query).